# Recursive method causes StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming

I am a new C# learner from Hong Kong.

Someone asks me the question typically known as the Egg Dropping Problem with below youtube link:-

https://youtu.be/o_AJ3VWQMzA

In an attempt to solve such problem, I wrote the below C# script and ran it on Visual Studio Code but faced "Stack Overflow" error. Where T is the number of Floors of the hypothetical building, N is the number of Eggs on hand and M is the number of times of trial.

I have spent plenty of time trying to debug but in vain. Grateful for any help, please.

Code:

```
using System;

namespace Double_Egg
{
    class Program
    {
        static int k=1, v1=0, v2=0, v3=0, minv=0, mink;

        static int DE(int T, int N)
        {
            if(T==1)
                return(1);
            else if(N==1)
                return(T);
            else
            {   
                minv=Math.Max(DE(1,N-1),DE(T-1,N));
                mink=1;

                for(k=2; k<=T; k++)
                {  
                    v1= DE(k,N-1);
                    v2=DE(T-k,N);
                    v3=Math.Max(v1,v2);

                    if(v3<minv)
                    {
                        minv=v3;
                        mink=k;
                    }
                }

                return(Math.Max(DE(mink, N-1),DE(T-mink,N))+1);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int T=1, N=1, M=1;

            Console.Write("Please enter number of Floors(T):");
            T=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Please enter numer of eggs(N):");
            N=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            M=DE(T,N);
            Console.WriteLine("The minimum number of throwing test(M) is: " + M);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the rules of the site before posting. No tags in your question title, please. Please ensure your question title describes the problem you're experiencing, not what you're working on. For example: "My code is producing a StackOverflowException when I xxxx"

Comment: As for StackOverflowException: your DE method calls itself. Presumably it's ending up in and endless recursive loop.

Comment: You should use descriptive variable names instead of short single-letter names. We have no idea what `k` and `DE` are meant to represent. While programming 
necessarily involves lots of algebra - it doesn't mean programs should resemble cryptic mathematics homework exercises.

Comment: I've tried to fix the layout somewhat to make it easier to read.

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: Sidenote: You can replace `minv=Math.Max(DE(1,N-1),DE(T-1,N));` with `minv=Math.Max(1,DE(T-1,N));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Step 1: Housekeeping

Let's start with some house-keeping. Here's the exact same code you posted, but I've given the variables descriptive names and formatted the code for readability:

```
using System;

namespace Double_Egg
{
    class Program
    {
        static int floor             = 1;
        static int changeFloorResult = 0;
        static int changeEggResult   = 0;
        static int bestChangeResult  = 0;
        static int bestResult        = 0;
        static int minFloor;

        static int RunDropEggAlgorithm( int numberOfFloors, int numberOfEggs )
        {
            if( numberOfFloors == 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if( numberOfEggs == 1 )
                {
                    return numberOfFloors;
                }
                else
                {   
                    bestResult = Math.Max( RunDropEggAlgorithm( 1, numberOfEggs - 1 ), RunDropEggAlgorithm( numberOfFloors - 1, numberOfEggs ) );
                    minFloor = 1;
                    for( floor = 2; floor <= numberOfFloors; floor++ )
                    {  
                        changeFloorResult = RunDropEggAlgorithm( floor, numberOfEggs - 1 );
                        changeEggResult   = RunDropEggAlgorithm( numberOfFloors - floor, numberOfEggs );
                        bestChangeResult = Math.Max( changeFloorResult, changeEggResult );
                        if( bestChangeResult < bestResult )
                        {
                            bestResult = bestChangeResult;
                            minFloor = floor;
                        }
                    }

                    return Math.Max(
                        RunDropEggAlgorithm( minFloor, numberOfEggs - 1 ),
                        RunDropEggAlgorithm( numberOfFloors - minFloor, numberOfEggs )
                    ) + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            int numberOfFloors = 1;
            int numberOfEggs   = 1;
            int result         = 1;

            Console.Write("Please enter number of Floors:");
            numberOfFloors = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine() );

            Console.Write("Please enter numer of eggs:");
            numberOfEggs   = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine() );

            result = RunDropEggAlgorithm( numberOfFloors, numberOfEggs );
            Console.WriteLine("The minimum number of throwing test is:" + result);
        }
    }
}
```

### Step 2: Debugging

Now that we know what each variable actually represents, let's see what's causing the stack-overflow error:

When working with recursive algorithms, stack-overflows happen when some base-case or boundary condition isn't checked (e.g. failing to consider both `n == 0` and `n == 1` when implementing a Fibonacci Series generator).

[When I paste the code into DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dxQfzS), run it, and supply `floors: 2, eggs: 2` I get a timeout exception (this is because DotNetFiddle terminates the program before a `StackOverflowException` can occur) - but this is still sufficient to identify the problem through visual inspection (I don't have a C# step-through debugger on my current computer anyway).

A quick-and-dirty way to debug it is to print the `RunDropEggAlgorithm` parameter arguments every time the method is entered:

```
[...]
static int RunDropEggAlgorithm( int numberOfFloors, int numberOfEggs )
{
    Console.WriteLine( nameof(RunDropEggAlgorithm) + " numberOfFloors: {0}, numberOfEggs: {1}. Press [Enter] to continue...", numberOfFloors, numberOfEggs );
    Console.ReadLine();

    if( numberOfFloors == 1)
[...]
```

With this, we get this output when we run it with the same input:

```
Please enter number of Floors:2
Please enter numer of eggs:2
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 2, numberOfEggs: 2 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 1, numberOfEggs: 1 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 1, numberOfEggs: 2 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 2, numberOfEggs: 1 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 0, numberOfEggs: 2 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 1, numberOfEggs: 1 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: -1, numberOfEggs: 2 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 1, numberOfEggs: 1
>
```

Even without having watched the video you linked to, I suspect that `numberOfFloors` should NOT be `-1`, so if change the first two `if` statements of the `RunDropEggAlgorithm` from `== 1` to `<= 1` like so...:

```
[...]
static int RunDropEggAlgorithm( int numberOfFloors, int numberOfEggs )
{
    Console.WriteLine( nameof(RunDropEggAlgorithm) + " numberOfFloors: {0}, numberOfEggs: {1} Press [Enter] to continue...", numberOfFloors, numberOfEggs );
    Console.ReadLine();

    if( numberOfFloors <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if( numberOfEggs <= 1 )
        {
            return numberOfFloors;
        }
[...]
```

...then I get this output, which I assume is correct:

```
Please enter number of Floors:2
Please enter numer of eggs:2
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 2, numberOfEggs: 2 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 1, numberOfEggs: 1 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 1, numberOfEggs: 2 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 2, numberOfEggs: 1 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 0, numberOfEggs: 2 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 1, numberOfEggs: 1 
RunDropEggAlgorithm numberOfFloors: 1, numberOfEggs: 2 

The minimum number of throwing test is:2
```

Comment: Tyvm Dai. Pardon for my being unprofessional. Its my first question on StackOverflow

Comment: @Martin if Dai has solved your problem, you should click the checkmark (✔) next to Dai's answer. This tells other people that your problem has been solved, and you both get a bit of reputation from it.

Comment: Thanks John for teaching me of the courtesy on StackOverflow.
Thanks Dai, for the detailed answer with inspiring elaboration of how the problem is solve.